# Decoding JSON with fetch and TypeScript throws eslint "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function" error

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have the following code that tries to do a AJAX-request, then decode the payload while maintaining types all the way through:

```
export function fetchJson<T>(url: string, data: FetchDataTypes): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(url, {})
            .then((response: Response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    reject(response);
                } else {
                    return response.text() as Promise<string>;
                }
            })
            .then((text: string) => {
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(text) as T);
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            })
            .catch((err: Promise<void>) => reject(err));
    });
}
```

The problem is that eslint throws this error:

> Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  consistent-return

I have looked at the documentation, and I am pretty sure it is because the first `.then` callback has an inconsistency in return/no-returns. I have tried to mutate my code to either have returns or not, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to rewrite this code to make eslint happy again.

All related questions I could find were errors where the developer forgot to return from mapper methods etc, and I could not find them relevant to my scenario.

Edit: Just to be clear, I want to be able to call my function like this:

```
export const fetchSomeObject = (): Promise<SomeResponseType> =>
  fetchJson('/api/some-endpoint', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {},
  });
```

And then:

```
fetchSomeObject.then((response: SomeResponseType) => {
  [...]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could fix it by always `return`ing and tweaking the `.then` logic, it would be far better to [avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) entirely, sidestepping the issue completely. When there's an error in a Promise, you can `throw` inside it to stop the handler and make control flow go to the `catch`.

You should `catch` in the *consumer* of `fetchJson` - don't `catch` here, because then, when the fetch fails, you'll be returning something of the wrong type - when you `catch`, you return a *resolved* Promise, which is not desirable here.

If you want to `JSON.parse` a response, use the `.json()` method, not the `.text()` method, and it'll be done automatically.

Also note that there's no need to explicitly note the types when TS can already infer it.

```
export function fetchJson<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            } else {
                return response.json();
            }
        });
}

// Then in the consumer:
fetchJson<someType>('someURL')
    .then((result) => {
        // result is of type someType
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // handle errors here
    });
```